# saving a field to upper case in drupal 6?

Tags: php, drupal-6

In drupal event creation I have a cck text field called person.How to force the person field to save(in db) in upper case only ?

Comment: this is not core php , this is drupal

Answer (score 0):

Check out hook_nodeapi (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6)

You should be able to write a function in a module something that looks a little like this:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'presave' && $node->type == 'event') {
    $person = strtoupper($node->field_person[0]['value']);
    $node->field_person[0]['value'] = $person;
  }
}
```

Where it says ***event***, just replace with your machine-friendly content type name, and where it says ***field_person***, replace this with the machine name for your person field (probably ***field_person*** in your case.

If you wanna see if it works then put this in your the code before the end of the if statement (should be your CCK field all in uppercase..probably with a 1 after it, but just ignore that, it's just the `die()` :-))

```
die(print_r($person));
```

Answer (score 0):

for drupal 7 that works :

```
   function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
     if ($node->type == ('article') {       
       $node->title = ucfirst($node->title);
     }  
   }
```